# excel code needed for sorting by total, and by last letter

Tags: excel, sorting

Ok ill explain the title a little better.

Using excel:

I have a field called "PART" example data would be CV101R CV102R.
each part has a alternative part, example would be CV101RN  CV102RN.
now I need them to be sorted to look like the part numbers with N on the end are underneath there counterpart.
Normally a simple sort by part would do this.
Unfortunately there is a second column which is sales.
My excel needs to sort by sales amount top to bottom BUT still sort by the same part numbers.

so it will still read CV101L and CV101LN but CV101L is top sales for the sheet and below it is its N version with its own sales...these sales however may be low compared.

Is there a function to do this? or will it require additional sort columns etc?
As you can tell I don't use Excel much so I'm hoping there's a quick easy way hehe

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half the battle is understanding what you are trying to say. I think I understand for the most part - what do you mean by "low compared"?

I would suggest you learn about the excel functions LEN, RIGHT, and LEFT. They allow you to manipulate text cells(which is what your part numbers are).

Using these functions you can split up your part numbers into whatever groups you want.

```
=LEFT(A2,5) // this will grab the first five chracters from the left of the part number.

=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-5) // this will grab the right letter characters from your part number.

=RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2)-1) // This will split off any extra letters
```

Once you have the part numbers split up into seperate columns you can sort however you want using a custom sort:

[image: Basic Text Manipulation Example]

You should also learn CONCATENATE, FIND and MID - just for future reference.